# SyntaxError on swagger congif on nodejs fastify

Tags: node.js, swagger, fastify

I am getting a syntax error on trying to set up swagger on nodejs app. i use fastify framework for node. my config is based on this tutorial [how-to-build-blazing-fast-rest-apis-with-node-js-mongodb-fastify-and-swagger](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-blazing-fast-rest-apis-with-node-js-mongodb-fastify-and-swagger-114e062db0c9/)

this is my server.js :

```
const swagger = require('./main/config/swagger')
const routes = require('./main/routes/v1')
const config = require('./main/config')


const fastifylogger = {
  level: config.logger.level,
  file: config.logger.file,
  serializers: {
    res: (res) => ({
     statusCode: res.statusCode,
     request: res.input,
     payload: res.payload,
}),
},
} 
const fastify = require('fastify')({
 logger: config.logger.enabled ? fastifylogger : undefined,
 pluginTimeout: 1000,
})
fastify.register(require('fastify-swagger'), swagger.options)
fastify.ready(() => {
console.log('fastify server is ready')
fastify.swagger()
})

fastify.listen(config.server.port, '0.0.0.0')
```

and this is swagger.js file :

```
exports.options = {
 routePrefix: '/documentation',
 exposeRoute: true,
 swagger: {
 info: {
  title: 'Fastify API',
  description: 'Building a blazing fast REST API with Node.js, MongoDB, Fastify and Swagger',
  version: '1.0.0',
},
externalDocs: {
  url: 'https://swagger.io',
  description: 'Find more info here',
},
host: 'localhost',
schemes: ['http'],
consumes: ['application/json'],
produces: ['application/json'],
},
}
```

but when i go to this url : localhost:3002/documentation to see my swagger API i get this error: **SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse ()**
i don't know how should i debug this error and why this error ocurred!

Comment: it could be `logger: config.logger.enabled ? fastifylogger : undefined,` here that error is thrown when `JSON.parse(undefined)` is executed

Answer (score 0):

I guess `comma-dangle` 
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle

I suggest to check Your `swagger.js`

```
exports.options = {
    routePrefix: '/documentation',
    exposeRoute: true,
    swagger: {
        info: {
            title: 'Fastify API',
            description: 'Building a blazing fast REST API with Node.js, MongoDB, Fastify and Swagger',
            version: '1.0.0'
        },
        externalDocs: {
            url: 'https://swagger.io',
            description: 'Find more info here'
        },
        host: 'localhost',
        schemes: ['http'],
        consumes: ['application/json'],
        produces: ['application/json']
    }
}
```

---

Test this.

```
fastify.register(require('fastify-swagger'), {
    routePrefix: '/documentation',
    exposeRoute: true,
    swagger: {
        info: {
            title: 'Fastify API',
            description: 'Building a blazing fast REST API with Node.js, MongoDB, Fastify and Swagger',
            version: '1.0.0'
        },
        externalDocs: {
            url: 'https://swagger.io',
            description: 'Find more info here'
        },
        host: 'localhost',
        schemes: ['http'],
        consumes: ['application/json'],
        produces: ['application/json']
    }
});
```

---

last try...

```
// move .swagger() code
// move under line `listen`

await fastify.listen(3000)
fastify.swagger()
fastify.log.info(`listening on ${fastify.server.address().port}`)
```

Comment: @FatemeAhmadi I think more.. wait a minutes. 
Perhaps can you share the code?

Comment: what part of my code you need? sorry this code is not upload on public git

Comment: @FatemeAhmadi test this.

Comment: @Fateme Ahmadi hmm sorry.. last try..;;TT

Comment: no .. this does not work. but I understood something.based on  **additional** part of [https://github.com/fastify/fastify-swagger]  i try to link http://localhost:3002/documentation/json and i see all my API in JSON format in this link! it looks like my ui swagger does not work properly

Comment: @FatemeAhmadi sorry. It didn't help.

Comment: thank you very much. i found this bug! in server.js i use fastify.addHook and when i commented this line all things work properly! :)